# XSLT remove node depending on language context

Tags: xslt

I'm having trouble on applying a stylesheet for the following problem: This is my given XML-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<STEP-ProductInformation>
  <Products>
    <Product ID="prd_ProdVar-286244">
      <Values>
        <ValueGroup AttributeID="tec_att_ignore_basic_data_text" ID="Y">
          <Value ID="Y" LOVQualifierID="en-US">Yes</Value>
          <Value ID="Y" LOVQualifierID="std.lang.all">Yes</Value>
          <Value ID="N" LOVQualifierID="de-DE">Ja</Value>
        </ValueGroup>
        <Value AttributeID="prd_att_description" Inherited="1" QualifierID="de-DE">
            Some text in german
        </Value>
        <Value AttributeID="prd_att_description" Inherited="5" QualifierID="en-US">
            Some text in english
        </Value>
    </Product>
  </Products>
</STEP-ProductInformation>
```

As you can see, I have a `ValueGroup` with (in this case) `Y` and `N`, which means, I wanna remove all `prd_att_description` from my final file which relate to the qualifierID where there is an "Y" representing it. If the `LOVQualifierID` is equal to `N` like in the german case, that Attribute should be kept.

I did try figuring it out and ended up with this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@prd_att_description[../@tec_att_ignore_basic_data_text = 'Y']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but that is obviously wrong, since it doesn't take into consideration what context is nor does it delete the nodes anyway.

**Expected output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<STEP-ProductInformation>
  <Products>
    <Product ID="prd_ProdVar-286244">
      <Values>
        <ValueGroup AttributeID="tec_att_ignore_basic_data_text" ID="Y">
          <Value ID="Y" LOVQualifierID="en-US">Yes</Value>
          <Value ID="Y" LOVQualifierID="std.lang.all">Yes</Value>
          <Value ID="N" LOVQualifierID="de-DE">Ja</Value>
        </ValueGroup>
        <Value AttributeID="prd_att_description" Inherited="1" QualifierID="de-DE">
            Some text in german
        </Value>
        <!-- english part stripped/removed -->
    </Product>
  </Products>
</STEP-ProductInformation>
```

As you can see: since the value-ID of `<Value ID="N" LOVQualifierID="de-DE">Ja</Value>` is `N` in german, it is kept. English has a `Y` and is thus removed.

Any help appreciated

Comment: There is no `@prd_att_description` in the input XML. Which node exactly do you want to remove? Please add the expected output to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am having trouble following your description of the logic that needs to be applied here. Is it possible that what you want to do is actually:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="lov" match="ValueGroup[@AttributeID='tec_att_ignore_basic_data_text']/Value" use="@LOVQualifierID" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Value[@AttributeID='prd_att_description'][key('lov', @QualifierID)/@ID='Y']"/>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this stylesheet processes a `Value` whose `AttributeID` is `"prd_att_description"`, it looks up the related `Value` from the `ValueGroup` whose `AttributeID` is `"tec_att_ignore_basic_data_text"`, using a [**key**](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#key) to match the `QualifierID` attribute to the `LOVQualifierID` attribute. If the matched `Value`'s `ID` is `"Y"`, the processed `Value` is removed.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! Sorry for not making it more clear. Works perfect! Thank you so much